# How do I get images to update dynamically with a slider in actionscript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3

Here is my dilemma. We use image stacks a lot here with alpha channels. I want to call up images in series using a slider. I am getting a concatenated string a pull up an image from my folder. But I can not get the images to load dynamically when I slide the slider bar.

I am using the frame number to change the file name to pull up the next frame. I can get the image to show up if I put the loader outside of the function, but when I put the loader in the function I get error after error saying the file cannot be located.

Here is the code as it currently stands :

```
var imgLoader = new Loader();
var str1 = String (".jpg");
var sliderValue:uint = mySlider.sliderKnob.x / 3;
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
function onEnterFrame(event:Event):void {
    sliderValue = mySlider.sliderKnob.x / 3;
    status_txt.text = "Slider position is: "+sliderValue;
    fileText.text = "Sketch_0"+sliderValue+".jpg";
    imgLoader.load( new URLRequest ( "Sketch_0"+sliderValue+".jpg"));
addChild(imgLoader);
setChildIndex(imgLoader, 0); 
}
```

Comment: 1. Why are you doing it in ENTER_FRAME handler? You are aware you force the same Loader object to request files over and over, 25-30-60 times per second, right? 2. Are filenames correct? 3. Relative paths, maybe?

Comment: I'm not using enter frame for any particular reason, other than I am bad at this. Is there a way to have it up date only when I move the slider? Is there a move listener event?

Answer (score 0):

First thing up, you need to load one image without that slider stuff and see if it loads. Verify the paths if not. Relative paths, as you put them, will work relatively to the folder where SWF is (or where the HTML page, containing the SWF, is).

Second, relieve the heavy burden you are trying to put on the Flash Player.

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onFrame);

var nextName:String;

function onFrame(e:Event):void
{
    var anIndex:int = mySlider.sliderKnob.x / 3;
    var aName:String = "Sketch_0" + anIndex + ".jpg";

    status_txt.text = "Slider position is: " + anIndex;
    fileText.text = aName;

    // Flash Player does not load images instantly,
    // so lets request new image only if user stopped moving the slider.
    if (aName == nextName)
    {
        loadNext(nextName);
    }
    else
    {
        nextName = aName;
    }
}

var currentName:String;
var currentImage:Loader;

function loadNext(value:String):void
{
    // If the requested file is the same as current, just ignore the request.
    if (value == currentName) return;

    currentName = value;

    // Dispose of the previous image in a proper way.
    if (currentImage)
    {
        removeChild(currentImage);

        currentImage.unloadAndStop(true);
        currentImage = null;
    }

    // Create a new one.
    var aRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(currentName);

    currentImage = new Loader();
    currentImage.load(aRequest);

    addChild(currentImage);
}
```

Comment: I was able to check this out. Looks like it works. Thank you for the help. One thing... I have more changes, could you (Organis) PM me so I can ask directly? I could use the help of an expert, and I want to be legit about it. Thanks.

Comment: @H.G. That's exactly what this site is about. You work, then you hit some problem you don't yet understand, yo go here, you show what you've done so far, you explain your problem, you get help. There are many highly skilled people here, you will be eventually helped by someone. Or not - if you don't show enough effort on your own - that happens too.

Comment: Well, here is the second issue. The delete image command you put in works great, but performing that operation prior to reading the new file is causing the image to appear to flash on and off. I tried moving the code down, but it is no longer the child, but the parent. I tried to modify the code, but it's not working. Here is how I modified the script in that area...

Comment: // Create a new one.
    var aRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(currentName);

    currentImage = new Loader();
    currentImage.load(aRequest);
  // Dispose of the previous image in a proper way.
  if (parent.currentImage)
  {
      removeChild(currentImage);

      currentImage.unloadAndStop(true);
       currentImage = null;
   }

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure how to set the format to be code. It prompted me in the first post, but this time it just showed as text.

Comment: @H.G. That's exactly what this site is about. You work, then you hit some problem you don't yet understand, yo go here, you show what you've done so far, you explain your problem, you get help. There are many highly skilled people here, you will be eventually helped by someone. Or not - if you don't show enough effort on your own - that happens too. –            I was trying to pay you for your time. That's all...

Comment: Woot.. I got it working by just deleting child at (1). that seemed to work without the flashing... not sure if that is fancy, but I brute forced it and I can refine as I have time.

Comment: @H.G. Ah, I get it. It will still flash if you run it over not-so-fast internet connection. The image flashes because it is not loaded when you add it, and the previous one goes away. In this case you should either preload all the images or to load them smartly and switch images only when the new one is finally loaded.